# How to fetch Row counts into a variable in ODI?

Tags: oracle11g, etl, oracle-data-integrator, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I am using Oracle Data Integrator 11g, I have designed a package with 2 interfaces in Oracle Data Integrator. Both the interfaces are inserting some records into target table (Which is in Oracle).

These 2 interfaces are working fine. But i want to capture the record counts from both the interfaces and i have to load those counts into a new audit log table.

Is there any option to do that? If so, kindly reply with your answers.

Answer (score 1):

The [getPrevStepLog()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/integrate.1111/e12645/odiref_reference.htm#ODIKD1237) method from the Substitution API allows to retrieve all kind of information on the previous step execution, including the number of rows inserted with the INSERT_COUNT parameter.

If you want to store that value in a variable, you can use this kind of refresh query for the variable and place it just after the interface in the package in refresh mode :

```
SELECT '<%=odiRef.getPrevStepLog("INSERT_COUNT")%>' FROM DUAL
```

Comment: By the way, do you know how to get this information from previous task within interface or procedure (not from previous step).  `odiref.getNBInsert()` always gives `0`.